# How to filter in Rails the records of table using last part of a string IN an Array of values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Here is what I have build in the model class

```
class Organization < ApplicationRecord
...
  scope :filter_by_domestic, ->(host_name_designation) do
    joins("LEFT JOIN events ON events.organization_id = organizations.id").
      where(events: { host_name: host_name_designation })
  end

end
```

I am getting correct results when I am using something like this:

```
@organizations = Organization.filter_by_domestic ['www.abc.com', 'www.xyz.com']
```

But I would like to improve the query and get the results only on the last part of the `host_name`, something like all records for which `host_name` ends with the substring `.com`.
I need to apply `split('.')last` for this `where(events: { host_name: host_name_designation })` and I don't know the correct syntax for this.
What is the correct statement here, in my case?

I want to be able to write something like:

```
  scope :filter_by_domestic, ->(host_name_designation) do
    joins("LEFT JOIN events ON events.organization_id = organizations.id").
      where(events: { '.' + host_name:.split('.').last host_name_designation })
  end
```

I need `where` to return something like this:

```
 '.' + Event.first.host_name.split('.').last
  Event Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "events".* FROM "events" ORDER BY "events"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> ".com"
```

Practically I need only the last part of the `host_name` to be used in the `where` clause. I know how to build my own `where` clause to achieve this, but I am looking to have the query generated instead of developed.

Any clue?

Comment: What database are you using? Postgres syntax will look a bit different than MySQL. I believe the query in the where can't be written in pure activerecord but needs to be written in the database query language.

Comment: I am using Postgres. However I can build myself the entire where clause in SQL but I want one generated and not developed.

Comment: You can use Postgres array, regular expressions etc inside Rails scopes. That's what u need to do here .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, looks like the solution I am looking for does not exists most probably due to some limitations in ActiveRecord.